# DotNetNuke Empty Project Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, dotnetnuke

I'm working On my first DotNetNuke project and when I create new one I got this list of error on first Compile:

```
    Warning 1   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Components\FeatureController.vb 11  9   DNNModule1
Warning 2   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Services.Search' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Components\FeatureController.vb 12  9   DNNModule1
Warning 3   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\DNNModule1ModuleBase.vb 11  9   DNNModule1
Error   4   Type 'PortalModuleBase' is not defined. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\DNNModule1ModuleBase.vb 24  14  DNNModule1
Warning 5   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\DNNModule1SettingsBase.vb   11  9   DNNModule1
Error   6   Type 'ModuleSettingsBase' is not defined.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\DNNModule1SettingsBase.vb   24  14  DNNModule1
Warning 7   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Data\DataProvider.vb    11  9   DNNModule1
Error   8   'Framework' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Data\DataProvider.vb    36  33  DNNModule1
Warning 9   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Edit.ascx.vb    10  9   DNNModule1
Warning 10  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Edit.ascx.vb    11  9   DNNModule1
Warning 11  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Edit.ascx.vb    12  9   DNNModule1
Warning 12  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Services.Localization' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.    c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Edit.ascx.vb    13  9   DNNModule1
Error   13  Event 'Load' cannot be found.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Edit.ascx.vb    39  86  DNNModule1
Error   14  'Exceptions' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Edit.ascx.vb    43  13  DNNModule1
Warning 15  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.    c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\SqlDataProvider.vb  13  9   DNNModule1
Warning 16  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\SqlDataProvider.vb  15  9   DNNModule1
Warning 17  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Framework.Providers' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\SqlDataProvider.vb  16  9   DNNModule1
Error   18  Type 'ProviderConfiguration' is not defined.    c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\SqlDataProvider.vb  43  43  DNNModule1
Error   19  Type expected.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\SqlDataProvider.vb  56  32  DNNModule1
Error   20  'Config' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\SqlDataProvider.vb  61  33  DNNModule1
Error   21  'DotNetNuke' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\SqlDataProvider.vb  121 20  DNNModule1
Warning 22  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Settings.ascx.vb    10  9   DNNModule1
Warning 23  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Settings.ascx.vb    11  9   DNNModule1
Error   24  sub 'LoadSettings' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a sub in a base class.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Settings.ascx.vb    47  26  DNNModule1
Error   25  Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Settings.ascx.vb    49  17  DNNModule1
Error   26  'ProcessModuleLoadException' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Settings.ascx.vb    62  13  DNNModule1
Error   27  sub 'UpdateSettings' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a sub in a base class. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Settings.ascx.vb    75  26  DNNModule1
Error   28  Type 'Entities.Modules.ModuleController' is not defined.    c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Settings.ascx.vb    77  35  DNNModule1
Error   29  'ProcessModuleLoadException' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\Settings.ascx.vb    87  13  DNNModule1
Warning 30  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    10  9   DNNModule1
Warning 31  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    11  9   DNNModule1
Warning 32  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    12  9   DNNModule1
Warning 33  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    13  9   DNNModule1
Warning 34  Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'DotNetNuke.Services.Localization' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.    c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    14  9   DNNModule1
Error   35  Type 'IActionable' is not defined.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    29  16  DNNModule1
Error   36  Event 'Load' cannot be found.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    40  86  DNNModule1
Error   37  'Exceptions' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    44  13  DNNModule1
Error   38  Type 'ModuleActionCollection' is not defined.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    59  49  DNNModule1
Error   39  Type 'IActionable' is not defined.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    59  83  DNNModule1
Error   40  Type 'ModuleActionCollection' is not defined.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    61  32  DNNModule1
Error   41  'GetNextActionID' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    62  25  DNNModule1
Error   42  'Localization' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    62  42  DNNModule1
Error   43  'LocalResourceFile' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    62  79  DNNModule1
Error   44  'Entities' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    62  99  DNNModule1
Error   45  'EditUrl' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.  c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    62  161 DNNModule1
Error   46  'DotNetNuke' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   c:\users\administrateur\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\DNNModule1\DNNModule1\View.ascx.vb    62  179 DNNModule1
Warning 47  Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DotNetNuke". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.   DNNModule1
Warning 48  Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. DNNModule1
Warning 49  The referenced component 'DotNetNuke' could not be found.   DNNModule1
Warning 50  The referenced component 'Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data' could not be found.     DNNModule1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using my templates http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com be sure to follow the DNN development environment setup instructions http://www.christoc.com/tutorials/aid/1

The templates follow a very specific format for development that has been tweaked after many years of doing DNN development, if you follow that format you'll find DNN development a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

This could also be due to you having a project that's compiling against an older version of .Net than DNN.  For example, your project is .Net 3.5 and the version that DNN is compiled against is .Net 4.0.

Comment: Yes.  For example... dev'ing module using Christoc.com DNN templates for VS 2013 will target .NET 4.0.  And this would be fine if that is the version of .NET targeted by the DNN version.  However, in my case, I just downloaded the DNN 8, and find I need to retarget to .NET 4.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the project was not able to find DotNetNuke.dll and Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll.

Look at your references section and you should see warning symbols on those two refefences.  Simply remove them and add references with the proper path.

OR - Ideally use NuGet to grab the package - http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2013/07/25/enterprise-extension-development-with-dnn-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and now its resolved

Remove references of `DotNetNuke`, `DotNetNuke.web` and `Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll` than navigate to DNN website that you have configured in IIS something like `dnndev.me` go to `bin` folder and find these references just add them and your problem will be solved